# R: applying function on individual csv's in a directory, saving them as one large csv

Tags: r

So I have a directory of folders (each a year, from 1990-2015), that each have over 100+ csv's:

```
data/1990/alabama.csv
data/1990/alaska.csv
data/1990/arizona.csv
...
data/1991/alabama.csv
data/1991/alaska.csv
data/1991/arizona.csv
...etc.
```

I'm applying a function that cleans up each of those csv's, and save it out into another folder.

So far I have this for loop that grabs all the file names and puts them in a data frame, where each row is a new year:

```
filepath <- "~/Desktop/project/data"
setwd(dir = filepath)
top_file_dir = dir()
indi_file_name = sapply(top_file_dir, dir)

filename = as.data.frame("", nrow = length(top_file_dir), ncol = 5000, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
for (i in 1:length(top_file_dir)){
  indi_file_name = sapply(top_file_dir[i], dir)
  for (j in 1:length(indi_file_name))
filename[i,j] = paste(top_file_dir[i],indi_file_name[j],sep="/")
}
```

Then I have a fairly simple function that goes through and tidies up the dataset:

```
general_clean <- function(currfile=filename) {
  geo <- read.csv(file=paste(filepath,currfile,sep="/") , stringsAsFactors=FALSE, colClasses = c("area_fips"="character"))

# remove unwanted columns
keep <- c("area_fips", "year", "area_title")
geoClean <- geo[keep]

# export new data into csv
save_file = paste("~/Desktop/project/output",substring(currfile,21,last=1000),sep="/")
write.csv(geoClean, file=save_file)
}

# apply function, input each year by hand...[1,]=1990, [2,]=1991, etc.
sapply(filename[1,], general_clean)
```

Which works ok, but I'd like to add a step that puts each of these smaller csv's into a new one for each year. This seems to involve creating an empty list and using rbind within the "general_clean" function to keep adding new data? But this is beyond my R abilities and everything I've tried so far is mostly guesswork. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close. Taking advantage of `list.file(..., full.names = TRUE)` to save a bunch of the `paste()` calls.

```
years <- list.dirs("~/Desktop/project/data", full.names = T, recursive = F)
# list only the folders in this folder "data"

general_clean <- function(file) {
    geo <- read.csv(file = file,
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                    colClasses = c("area_fips"="character"))
    keep <- c("area_fips", "year", "area_title") # move all cleaning into your fxn
    geoClean <- geo[keep]
    return(geoClean)
}
# move all your cleaning steps into your fxn

for (y in years) {
    year_name <- gsub(".*data/(\\d{4}/.*", "//1", y) # make a year name chr vector
    states <- dir(y, full.names = T) # now list all files in each year
    readin_list <- lapply(states, geoClean) # list of small data frames
    readin_dataframe <- do.call(rbind, readin_list) # make it into a big one
    write.csv(readin_dataframe, paste0("output/", year_name, "/")) # write it out
}
```

I'm 99% sure this won't work perfectly the first time, but since I can't see all of your data it's my best guess and a good place to start. Let me know what goes wrong and we can get it working on your data :)